# Using both Sass (Scss) and Less in an Angular 7+ project

Tags: angular, sass, less, angular-cli

Creating a project and specifying a CSS preprocessor is straightforward

```
ng new my-app --style=scss
          ... --style=sass
          ... --style=less
```

Setting the default to an existing project too

```
ng config schematics.@schematics/angular:component.styleext scss
                                                        ... sass
                                                        ... less
```

But what if I want to use both `Sass` and `Less`?
Is this possible?

I'd like to integrate both `Ng-zorro`, which uses `Less`, and `Clarity`, which uses `Sass` for customizations.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By setting the default CSS extension you just say what should be created when you run

```
ng g component test
```

Then the component will have styles file with extension you configured.

Anyway, it does not mean you cannot use both.

Just change the extension of generated file to `.less` and adapt the reference in the component.

```
styleUrls: ['./test.component.less'],
```

or even leave both files:

```
styleUrls: ['./test.component.less', './test.component.scss'],
```

So, you have one of your style files as `less` now.

In the end of the day you can have all possible CSS dialects mixed in your project.

Comment: Thank you! So basically Angular already has all what's needed for both Sass and Less. I would add to your answer that it might be required to run `npm rebuild node-sass` because of "missing bindings"

Comment: @LppEdd that could be. However it could also be that latest sass binary has been changed since you installed @angular/cli. This is normally a different issue, probably you didn't face the problem because you didn't use sass and the problem couldn't even appear

Comment: You're right, I tested your suggestion in a fresh project created without setting a preprocessor.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a little addition: This also works globally.

angular.json:

```
  "architect": {
    "build": {
     ..
      "options": {
       ..
        "styles": [
          "src/styles.less",
          "src/styles.scss"
        ]
```

Both files will be used no matters what dialect you're using.